# While loop not iterating through file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to add IDs to a file. The file looks like this:

```
field1:field2:field3:field4
```

I want to check if the second field already exists (output a message to the user) or if it doesn't (add it to the file once I get more information from the user). I've written a loop to accomplish this but whenever I run this part of the script it just lags and never executes. I think the issue is that my while loop isn't capturing each line properly.

```
 40 checkID()
 41 {
 42 
 43     local input
 44     local line
 45     while : ; do
 46         read -p "Enter id (or ENTER to quit):" input
 47         [ -z "$input" ] && return 1
 48         while read line; do
 49                 if ! grep -q "$(cut -d: -f2)" "$file"; then
 50                         echo "$input"
 51                 else    
 52                         error "id '$input' already exists in the file"
 53                 fi
 54         done
 55     done
 56 }
```

Comment: the **48** line indicates that it **need** a input from the stdin. Did you try to enter something? @Whoppa

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `while read` loop there at all, and you want `cut` to read from the file rather than the user.

To find something in the second column a file, you can use

```
if cut -d: -f2 "$file" | grep -q "$input"
then
    echo "Found it"
fi
```

Also note that this is a substring match, so if input is "foo", it will match a file where a second field is "food truck"

Comment: I want to check the second field of each line. I have ID stored in the second field of each line. The other fields store information that corresponds to that ID. Thats why I was using a while loop.